# org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=504 Error while trying to scrape HTML content

Tags: html, web-scraping, jsoup, httpurlconnection, http-status-code-504

I want to scrape the HTML codes from the URL listed below. The problem is, I get this error:-

> Aug 14, 2016 6:40:36 PM booksscraper.BooksScraper main
>   SEVERE: null
>   org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=504, URL=http://www.bkstr.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CourseMaterialsResultsView?catalogId=10001&categoryId=9604&storeId=10293&langId=-1&programId=636&termId=100043741&divisionDisplayName=%20&departmentDisplayName=ACCG&courseDisplayName=16971&sectionDisplayName=P15%20DAVIS&demoKey=d&purpose=browse
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:590)
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540)
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227)
>       at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:216)
>       at booksscraper.BooksScraper.main(BooksScraper.java:52)

I have set the timeout to infinity, but that did not help. The HTML code for this website is extremely large i.e. 14833 lines of code. Is this the reason for the problem?

```
String url = "http://www.bkstr.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/CourseMaterialsResultsView?catalogId=10001&categoryId=9604&storeId=10293&langId=-1&programId=636&termId=100043741&divisionDisplayName=%20&departmentDisplayName=ACCG&courseDisplayName=16971&sectionDisplayName=P15%20DAVIS&demoKey=d&purpose=browse";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .maxBodySize(0)
                .timeout(0)
                .get();

System.out.println(doc);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to connect to the website by setting the **UserAgent** as  **Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36**. But, it took about 4 minutes to respond.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Jsoup API or your code issue. The reason for the error message is that the **URL is not responding** and throwing "Gateway Timeout" error message (The proxy server did not receive a timely response from the upstream server).

**Exception message from your program:-**

> HTTP error fetching URL. Status=504

**HTTP Status code : 504**

> 504 Gateway Timeout
>
> The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not receive a
>   timely response from the upstream server specified by the URI (e.g.
>   HTTP, FTP, LDAP) or some other auxiliary server (e.g. DNS) it needed
>   to access in attempting to complete the request.
>
> ```
>   Note: Note to implementors: some deployed proxies are known to
>   return 400 or 500 when DNS lookups time out.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer notionquest. However, the Gateway Timeout only shows when we enter the URL directly. If we go to the URL through this  "[URL](http://www.bkstr.com/sheridandavisstore/shop/textbooks-and-course-materials?cm_sp=GlobalJuly122016BTS-_-ShipTextbooks-_-943)", no gateway timeout occurs.

How does this happen?